# Slider, display none elements also counts when click on previous and next button

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I have a slider, which has some `li` elements as `display:none`. Without `display:none` elements the slider works good. The issue is when i click prev or next button the `display:none` elements also counts and slides won't work properly. At some point when I click on `li`, I may have to show `display:none` elements too. What to do?

Here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/o4a6qot2/